# Are there any supported high bit-depth video or image formats in DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow

In the Microsoft DirectShow documentation there appear to be no RGB video or image formats with more than 8 bits per channel. There are some YUV formats with 10 or 16 bits per channel but I've not found much support for them by googling.

- [Video Subtype GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [10-bit and 16-bit YUV Video Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb970578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Are there any supported DirectShow formats or FourCC video or image formats (third party or not) for greater definition than 8 bits per channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectShow itself - as the framework - has no problems supporting 10 bpp and more, it's a matter of video renderers and video adapters to support these formats. Some professional hardware from Balckmagic definitely supports 10 bpp formats, including within DirectShow API.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks like Black Magic Design SDK and DirectShow filters support 'r210' 10-bit RGB and 'v210' 10-bit 4:2:2 YCbCr. Some links suggest v210 is the same as the corresponding QuickTime format. http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/R210/bmd_pixel_formats.pdf

Comment: Exactly, I did see v210 in action before - it really worked (just in case you need a real person who witnessed this :)

Comment: I tested v210, which is 4:2:2 but it does not give so called advertising quality yet. DPX i also tested which is so called 10-bit RGB using MediaExpress but quality is equal. I do not still know what is the quality of r210 pure 4:4:4 ? Anyone tested?

Comment: How do you check the quality?