# Are there any standard RGB in-memory formats for 10bits or more per channel

Tags: video, directshow

I need to support 10,12 or 16 bits per channel RGB information in a DirectShow pipeline (so 30bits per pixel or more excluding alpha). Are there any standard formats for this, perhaps described by a fourcc code, QuickTime type or DirectShow video format?

The higher bit depth formats I've found are YUV rather than RGB (though high-bit depth YUV format suggestions would be helpful too).The nearest I've found is 10bit per channel RGB 'r210' supported by BlackMagic hardware.

At the moment I'm considering creating my own private DirectShow interleaved format of 16bits per channel RGB and my own color converter filter to deal with conversion to standard DirectShow video formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow does not define standard RGB formats with bits per pixel greater than 8. Your custom media types will do fine though. As you noticed, there are more or less popular 10-bit YUV formats such as `v210` (not quite "standard" though) as discussed previously in  [Are there any supported high bit-depth video or image formats in DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352858/are-there-any-supported-high-bit-depth-video-or-image-formats-in-directshow)